# How to deploy jar/war to nexus in the docker build?

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment, docker, nexus

I currently following this methods for my maven java project in jenkins

1. created a compose file with maven image, and given a entry point command "mvn clean install"
2. Created a Dockerfile, From tomcat image. that will copy my war to ../webapps folder
3. Once the docker compose up is exited with the code 0, I am starting the docker build with the Dockerfile.
4. Then pushing the image to my registry

Now the problem is. I need to push my war to nexus.

I know , still we can achive by command mvn deploy ....

But is going like all we need to maintain for each and every project.

Previouly I used m2release plugin. that plugin have option to execute the try run and release run. once it done, it automatically change my pom to next vertion and commits to git.

Now I want to achieve that with docker build in jenkins. Or my way of doing is wrong? if yes, what is the correct solution for doing this?